# Error on installation of Oracle Database 10g on Windows XP (SP3)

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am trying to install Oracle Database 10g on Windows XP SP3 (It is a VM on Mac OS X).

After the first screen in installation program, it gives an error "The value for SID may contain only ...

Is there any hint ?

Comment: What is the value you're putting in for the sid during installation?

Answer (score 3):

It is solved by changing the name of default database from **global_db** to **globaldb**. Then everything is fine now. Don't Add any space.

Answer (score 1):

Do not include space in the DB name.